# iOS Splash Screen is brighter than main screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, splash-screen

I've never faced something like this, as you see in the attached gif the transition from splash screen to main screen with the same background image causes screen to get darker.

[image]

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Okay..that was weird but I found out that changing the background color of the view for both splashscreen.xib and the next screen to be the same solved it for me.

Comment: It is possible that your image is semi-transparent and that a white background on the splash-screen makes it seem brighter than a dimmer background on your main controller.

Comment: No..same image for both screens